# SharePoint Approval Workflow Using SharePoint Group in Condition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to check in a Condition rule if the user approving the Task is in a SharePoint Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no action to check group membership from a 2010 Designer workflow.

This could be accomplished with a Visual Studio workflow.